# Updated to 5.1 and now Game Center push notification doens't work.

Tags: xcode, game-center

I'm making a GKTurnedBased game, and everything was going great until I updated my iphones to 5.1 and xcode to 4.3.1. The game still works, the players get the turn, the badge is updated, but there are no longer any notifications when the user dones't have the app opened. I have made sure that notification is turned on in the settings app, both for game center and for my game. 
Please help!

Thanks

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple on this issue.  Mirror: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1599408 .  I suggest you do the same at bugreports.apple.com

Comment: I had issues registering push notification when they where enabled for development, in order to fix them I had to delete every certificate I had, and regenerate new certificates from Apple, after I got the new certificates they started working. I dunno if this helps, but you can try it..

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be a bug with iPhone/xcode so not much you can do but wait for a patch/update